# Is it possible to create new user profile by using command line for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, user-profile

For automation purpose, is it possible to create new user profile for Google Chrome using terminal?

Also, after creation of new user profile can we start chrome with the created one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Default google-chrome user profile data stored at `~/.config/google-chrome`.
If you want to create new profile then use command:

```
google-chrome --user-data-dir=test --first-run
```

It will create new profile data directory test. You can give any name to this directory and any location. It will keep cookies, history and all data relate to this user.
Next time if you want to use this profile then use command:

```
google-chrome --user-data-dir=test
```

Or you can make it default browser also.

**EDIT :** Thank you @[snoop](https://askubuntu.com/users/332494/snoop) for suggest

If you don't want to see default browser pop-up then you can use command:

```
google-chrome --user-data-dir=test --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check
```

It is discussed bug [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=348426).

Comment: During first run of user profile, it ask for `Make Google Chrome the default browser`, I mean pop-up comes, can we avoid that and directly open Chrome?

Comment: there is option `--no-default-browser-check` but it not working in my chrome. try if it is working in your .  `man google-chrome` says  ` Google  Chrome has hundreds of undocumented command-line flags that are
       added and removed at the whim of the  developers.   Here,  we  document
       relatively stable flags`   so may be remove or  not working with me.   you can find option here also  http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: Seems like its a bug:  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=348426. Workaround could be:  `google-chrome --user-data-dir=test2 --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check`

Comment: sure, please add this.

Comment: @snoop thanks , i made change in answer that you suggest  :)-